# Structure of parser in Clojure

Tags: parsing, clojure

I'm working on my first Clojure project, which is a parser. Since it's my first project I'm unsure of many aspects, from my general approach to solving this problem to the small implementation details. I also don't know anyone proficient in Clojure so any guidance is welcome.

In higher terms, my implementation will take a string (which is one message to be parsed) and break it into fields. Each field it will apply some function to (often a dictionary lookup), and finally return a dictionary of results.

```
(use 'clojure.string)

;; This defines the breakdown of each line in the file. The line contains an entry and start with something
;; like "1AXYZ ". In this case the first two characters ("1A") are the "Record Type" and the next four
;; ("XYZ ") are the "Entering Firm". This data structure holds that information.
(def parser
  {:shared '(  ; These are the entries shared amongst all types of message

          ;; Field-Name  num-chars
             Record-Type 2   
             Entering-Firm 4
             Clearing-Number 4
             Symbol 11
             Lot-Indicator 1
             ;;...
             )

   :1A     '(      ; this is one type of message, indicated with record-type=1A

          ;; Field-Name  num-chars
             Filler 9
             Poss-Dupe 1
             Booth-Booked-Indicator
             Order-Time 6
             Order-Date 8
             ;; ...
             )
   }
)


;; if no implementation is found for a field, just return a map to its contents.
(defn default [header x]
  {(str header) (trim (join x))})


;; most of the fields that dont use the default function will just be a dictionary lookup    
(defn Poss-Dupe [[x]] (default 'Poss-Dupe ({\1 "Odd Lot" \D "Rule 902" \E "Poss Dupe Rule 902" 
                                            \F "Auto Execution" \G "Poss Dupe of Auto-Execution" 
                                            \H "Non-auto Execution" \I "Poss Dupe of Non-auto Execution"
                                            \0 "" \space ""}
                                               x (str "ERROR: " x))))

(defn Booth-Booked-Indicator [[x]] (default 'Booth-Booked-Indicator ({\0 "Post" \1 "Booth" \2 "Booked"} x (str "ERROR: " x))))

(defn Order-Time [x] (default 'Order-Time (->> x (partition 2) (map join) (join ":")  ))) ; "HHMMSS" -> "HH:MM:SS"

(defn Order-Date [x] (default 'Order-Date 
                       (join "-" (map join (list (take 4 x) (take 2 (drop 4 x)) (drop 6 x)))))) ; "YYYYMMDD"->"YYYY-MM-DD"

(defn Filler [x] nil)


(defn try-call [f subseq]
  (try
    ((eval f) subseq)
    (catch Exception e  ; f not defined -> call default
      (default f subseq))))


;; Where the recursion happens
(defn grab-call [[f n & rest-instructions] line] 
  (let [[field rest-line] (split-at n line)]
    (if (or (empty? line) (not f)) 
      nil
      (merge (try-call f field) (grab-call rest-instructions rest-line)))))


;;; Entry point
(defn parse-line [line]
  (grab-call (concat (:shared parser) 
                     ((keyword (subs line 0 2)) parser)) 
    line ))
```

If you care to know the particulars of what is being parsed, that can be found at [NYSE MRO specs](https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/markets/nyse/SAH_MRO_Formats.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of weird stuff here.

- It's strange to have no `ns` form for defining your namespace and requiring the libraries you need. Putting a bare `use` at the top is gross.
- Don't `use` an entire namespace. Either `require` with an alias, like `(:require [clojure.string :as s]) ... (s/join ...)`, or else `require` and `refer` the specific stuff you use: `(:require [clojure.string :refer [join trim]]).
- The uppercase function names should be lowercase: `poss-dupe`, or even `possible-duplicate`, not `Poss-Dupe`
- There should be a newline after the parameter definitions for most functions: `(defn foo [x] \newline (...))`
- The `eval` is very suspicious, but I don't want to read your whole program and figure out what you should be doing instead. Probably `ns-resolve` or something.
- `(if (or (empty? x) f) nil y)` is a bad way to write `(when (and (seq x) f) y)`
- Usually calling `keyword` to look stuff up in a map suggests that you shouldn't be using keywords as keys, but in your case it looks fine-ish. However, instead of `((keyword whatever) m)`, it would be more readable to write `(get m (keyword whatever))`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! `ns-resolve` does exactly what I was using `eval` for--why is it preferred in general? And are you still (as you were in IRC) of the opinion that I should have an explicit map rather than just a function lookup? I was going for minimal boilerplate, but I don't want to sacrifice readability for that...

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you have to give your functions crappy names like Poss-Dupe, and you run the risk of executing arbitrary code if someone puts an `eval` into their CSV file or whatever it is you're parsing.

Comment: Haha, the field is called "Poss Dupe" in the original NYSE spec.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your scheme involving eval and ns-resolve means you have to give your functions names as crappy as those in the nyse spec, instead of functions with good names and a mapping from crappy names to good ones.

Comment: Ahh, that's a good point

Comment: Note that the only thing that is being `eval`ed (or `ns-resolve`d) is that original long list that I provide that defines the format of what is being parsed. So there isn't really any chance of mischief there (but that doesn't address the readability and explicit vs implicit considerations you brought up previously)

Answer (score 0):

Some points on idiomatic Clojure:

- Do not return `nil` from if statements: `(if condition? nil false-branch)` -> `(if-not condition? false-branch)`
- `defn` bodies in the next line unless they are truly one liners (not like in `Booth-Booked-Indicator`.
- Don't use `eval` but resolve the function and call it directly as `(f)`.

Conceptually:

- If you want to define your own types use `defrecord` and `deftype` (`defrecord` in this case). `Poss-Dupe`, `Order-Time Order-Date`, etc. should be records, and it might be cleaner if they use the same `fn` bindings, instead of `[[x]]` and `[x]`, only one of the two.
- Instead of defining of passing around a function, evaluating it, checking for a `NullPointerException`, and then going to the default implementation, consider using a protocol. For example, `IParse (parse [f])`. You can then implement `parse` for your different types and leave a default implementation. Then `try-call` will be just reduced to `-parse`.

Comment: `(eval f)` -> `(f)` is a totally wrong suggestion. Getting rid of the eval is great, but you completely change what the function does. Records and protocols don't make a lot of sense to me here, but I guess I don't understand the problem enough to say for sure that it is wrong.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "call it directly as (f)"--the following dummy example gives an error: `(def foo 'bar)
(defn bar [] (println "bar")) (foo)`